Is 'stop' not working with 'go perft' in SF a violation of UCI protocol?
According to the UCI protocol specs [ https://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/block/uci.htm ], when a 'stop' command is issued, the UCI engine should "stop calculating as soon as possible".
This is not the case however with 'perft' e.g. if you (accidentally) execute 'go perft 55' instead of 'go perft 5', you would have to kill SF, unless you want to wait another couple of years.
Since 'go' command is part of the UCI protocol, but 'perft' parameter is not, should 'stop' still be able to stop 'go perft'?
For me as a user, the answer is a "yes", but speaking strictly from the protocol perspective: is this a violation of the protocol or not?
